# How can I specify font as 'Italic' using NPOI 2.2.1.0?

Tags: c#, fonts, npoi, italic

I want to create my own style for cell in Ecxel document. I need cell text to be displayed as 'Italic' like this '*blablabla*'. How can I do it?
I tried something like this:

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
var font = wb.CreateFont();
font.SetItalic(true)
```

but there is no 'SetItalic' method in NPOI API, just readoly 'IsItalic' property.

Comment: Did you asked in the appropriate place first, as indicated on https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://npoi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NPOI/SS/UserModel/Font.cs), IsItalic is a read/write property.

Here is a little code sample demonstrating how to apply an italic font to a particular cell:

```
var wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");

// Create an italic font
var font = wb.CreateFont();
font.IsItalic = true;

// Create a dedicated cell style using that font 
var style = wb.CreateCellStyle();
style.SetFont(font);

var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);

row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Username");

var cell = row.CreateCell(1);
cell.SetCellValue("Email");
// Apply the cellstyle we craeted
cell.CellStyle = style;

using (var fileData = new FileStream(@"G:\scratch\sheet2.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
  wb.Write(fileData);
}
```

Comment: Thx, I was confused by that intellisence comment , I was thinking there is no setter

`get whether to use italics or not
* @return italics or not`